# How to pass request (HttpRequest) from urls.py to a callable object?

Tags: django, django-views

In urls.py I want to map a specific legacy URL to a specific dynamic resource:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('example.example',
    url(r'^example/example.html$', views.myview(request,url_slug='example-slug')),
)
```

With the view looking like this:

```
def myview(request, slug):
    a = get_object_or_404(MyObject, url_slug=slug)
```

How can I get the *request* parameter, or do this more cleanly?

Answer (score 2):

You're making this too complicated. Django's URLs already pass the request, and you can specify any additional parameters in the third argument of the url entry:

```
url(r'^example/example.html$', views.myview, {'url_slug': 'example-slug'})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good for the simple use case.  What if my use case were more complex, and I wanted to do some processing, prior to handing off to the view?